# SQL PreparedStatement; Am I doing it right?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am building a web app with a single (not pooled) full time (jdbc) connection between static classes and the database. This is expected to be a low traffic site and the static methods are synchronized. In an effort to speed up access to product information, I am trying PreparedStatements for the first time. As I test, on localhost, sure that I'm the only one running the app., it seems clear to me that my the prepared statements are slower than the unprepared statements I use earlier in the process. This may not be a fair comparison. The unprepared statements get a single result set from one table and it's done. As you can see from the code below, what I'm doing with prepared statements involves three tables and multiple queries. But since this is my first time, I would appreciate review and comment. This does actually work; i.e. all data is retrieved as expected.

The first method below (initialize()) is called once from a servlet init() method when the application is first started. The second method (getItemBatch()) retrieves information about as many product items as match a product name (Titel). My little development / test database has less than 100 (total) items and only 1-3 items matching each name; most often only 1. The server app and database are on the same machine and I'm accessing from a browser via localhost. I'm surprised by the consistent perceptible wait for this detailed product data compared to fetching a master product list (all items) mentioned above.

```
  public static boolean initialize (Connection connArg, String dbNameArg, String dbmsArg) {

    con = connArg;
    dbName = dbNameArg;
    dbms = dbmsArg;
    sqlserver_con = connArg;

    ItemBatchStatement =
          "select Cartnr, Hgrupp, Prisgrupp, Moms from dbo.Centralartregister " +
           "where Titel = ?";

    ForArtNrStatement =
          "select Artnr, Antal from dbo.Artikelregister " +
           "where Cartnr = ? and Antal > 0";

    ItemHgruppStatement =
            "select Namn from dbo.Huvudgrupper " +
             "where Hgrupp = ?";

    try {
      con.setAutoCommit(false);
      getItemBatch = con.prepareStatement(ItemBatchStatement);
      getForArtNr = con.prepareStatement(ForArtNrStatement);
      getItemHgrupp = con.prepareStatement(ItemHgruppStatement);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      return(false);
    } finally {
      try {con.setAutoCommit(true);} catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
    return(true);
  }
```

-

```
  public static synchronized String getItemBatch (String Titel) throws SQLException {

    String ret_xml;
    ResultSet rs  = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    ResultSet rs2 = null;

    Titel = charChange(Titel);
    ret_xml = "<ItemBatch Titel='" + Titel + "'>";
    try {
      con.setAutoCommit(false);
      getItemBatch.setString(1,Titel);
      rs = getItemBatch.executeQuery();
      while (rs.next()) {
        getForArtNr.setInt(1,rs.getInt("Cartnr"));
        rs1 = getForArtNr.executeQuery();
        getItemHgrupp.setInt(1,rs.getInt("Hgrupp"));
        rs2 = getItemHgrupp.executeQuery();
        if (rs1.next() && rs2.next()) {
          ret_xml += "<item><Hgrupp>" + rs2.getString("Namn") + "</Hgrupp><Price>" + rs.getInt("Prisgrupp") + "</Price><Moms>" + rs.getInt("Moms") + "</Moms><Cartnr>" + rs.getInt("Cartnr") + "</Cartnr><Artnr>" + rs1.getInt("Artnr") + "</Artnr></item>";
        }
      }
      ret_xml += "</ItemBatch>";
      return(ret_xml);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      return("SQLException: " + e);
    } finally {
      try {con.setAutoCommit(true);} catch (SQLException e) {}
      if (rs != null) {rs.close();}
      if (rs1 != null) {rs1.close();}
      if (rs2 != null) {rs2.close();}
    }
  }
```

.

**UPDATE:** I'm still googling and looking for ways to do better. Let me add something for your consideration.

I'm closing the prepared statements via the servlet's destroy() method; the same servlet that calls the method "initialize()" above in order to create them. The idea is to create them once (and only once) and have them available forever for all users (i.e. until the app or server is shut down). I'm going for a kind-of a pseudo-stored procedure. I would just use stored procedures straight out, but the database exists to support another application (their in-house sales system) and I'm going to use it for Internet sales read-only ... avoiding any potential conflict with their maintenance efforts or agreements etc. by not doing anything to change their database set-up. I have suggested that my app use a new account limited to read-only privileges. And come to think of it, I haven't tested whether I can use Prepared Statements in that mode; just seems like it should work.

Each result set is closed in the finally block in the method where they are created. I guess that's ok? I reuse the same RS variable name for multiple result sets (on the second two) but close only once. But wait! Do I even need that? The ResultSets are declared within the scope of the method. If resetting them without closing the old ones doesn't cause leaks, then exiting the method should do just as well on its own. It is a static method, but the ResultSets will be reset every time it's used (at the very least). So, at most, there would just be a single set of ResultSet handles available for reuse; not run-away "leakage."

I'm wondering if I can send the two select requests in the loop both at the same time, simply by turning them into one prepared statement separated by ';'. Or just found "MultipleActiveResultSets=True"; document allowing SQL Server to process multiple transaction requests on a single connection ... still investigating this. Or is there another way to create a prepared statement that would fetch ALL the data via a single submission? (Seems to me like there are too many round trips.) Finally, I might get a boost from using connection pooling, which I haven't done yet. It's low priority in my project right now, but I might have to do it before we go online.

Comment: Your HTML is vulnerable to injection attacks and won't work if items contain characters like `<` and `'`. You would do well to investigate a simple templating language like JSP instead of creating the HTML in code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this, so I'm open for any comments. I've been reading about injection since it's turned up so often when I google for info. I think I'm ok. Those characters are dealt with using javascript encoding techniques and my app doesn't allow free-form query. Mind if I wander off a bit, since you mention JSP? Back in the early days, I investigated JSP and all the examples involved reloading entire pages (sending the html) to make changes. I believe it's now possible to change specific data fields within web pages now, but don't know how nice that is compared with dhtml.

Comment: If your code is working then this question is more appropriate for [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You will get more responses there.

Comment: Reading http://kunststube.net/escapism/ will give you a good background. Unless you're html-escaping the data before you put it in the database, you're vulnerable. (And really, the data in the DB ought to be 'pure', un-escaped data, to be escaped just before being output). I wouldn't worry about JSP reloading entire pages: the delay is barely noticeable compared to the overhead of the DB call, usually.

Comment: @Perception  Wow! The code review beta looks interesting. I'll check it out.

Comment: @artbristol I'm escaping data using String encoding techniques in javascript. I've tested it against input data with a variety of special characters. In addition, it supports foreign languages to UTF-8 within the Java code. See also, my unrelated demo at: http://isr.servequake.com:8181/ws/WebSocketTest.htm

Comment: Umm, encoding and escaping are similar but not the same thing. I won't go into more detail (read the link I sent you), but javascript won't save you.

Comment: See if you can break or attack my demo at the link above.

Comment: Or give an example of something you don't think will work in the code above, and I'll try it.

Comment: `<ItemBatch Titel='" + Titel + "'>` for example, won't work if `Titel` has `'` in it. `isr.nu` appears to be down otherwise I'd have a look at your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create web applicaton and use some web container like tomcat, jetty etc you always can use jdbc datasource and connection pool. It is simple. Good explanation gives [here](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html)

If you don't want to use connection pool  I suppose it would be better use Method Scope Connections described link above

Comment: Thanks. As described above, I'm currently using the method described under JDBC Connection Scope; i.e. opening the connection when the servlet is loaded and destroying it when it is unloaded. Static (Java) objects also remain available so there is no object loading time. Synchronization is used to avoid confusion. I realize this will not scale up well, and I will need to revisit it if this website ever starts getting high traffic or if the app is generalized as a product.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to give you the wrong impression. It's a good suggestion and I have been looking into it. Under time pressure, it's just a low priority right now for the reasons given. I start off fetching data as the web page loads, so I want a live connection immediately and don't want to wait otherwise; so Method Scope doesn't seem right for me. Connection pooling (Tomcat) does seem like a good idea, and I'll likely do that when I have the time. But I may go online with this in one month as is.